# HTMX sometimes redirects to a page fragment instead of placing it in the page

Tags: htmx

I'm using HTMX to replace a fragment of page every 30 seconds using the following code:

```
    <ul hx-get="/refresh" hx-trigger="every 30s" id="today" hx-select="#today" hx-target="#today" hx-swap="outerHTML">
```

This works perfectly most of the time. However when I leave the page open I sometimes come back and find it has redirected to the hx-get url ("/refresh" in the example). So it's showing just the unstyled fragment and the url bar shows the fragment url.

I think this might be something to do with the behaviour that is intended to show errors when they occur, but the page shown isn't an error. I think was happened is that HTMX got a transient error (maybe a drop in my internet connection when my laptop went to sleep) then just redirected to the page to show it but by the time it loaded the error was gone.

Any way to fix this? Assuming my assumption above is correct I think I'd like to silently drop errors for this particular element rather than redirecting to them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does the `/refresh` endpoint look like on the backend?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean? It just serves a fragment of HTML with status 200. It's a normal django view using the `render` shortcut function.

Comment: You can redirect the frontend by setting a response header like `HX-Location` or `HX-Redirect`. I was wondering whether the view function of `/refresh` endpoint could do such thing or not. I tried this setup with a simulated network error, but HTMX did not redirect the frontend to the `hx-get` endpoint. So maybe a 3rd party script causes this behavior. Can you share some more information? E.g. do you use another JS framework, that makes network requests, what is in the Django access logfile during the incident? Etc.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Sounds like it's not a built in feature of HTMX as I thought it might be. I'll investigate more and update this question when I figure it out!